# Serializing ExpandoObject with json.Net

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following code, where `page.Fields` is an `ExpandoObject`. I'm iterating through some user-defined properties and adding them to an Expando, cast to an `IDictionary<string,string>` to allow me to add new field name / values dynamically, but when I set the `Fields` property to the value of `props`, serializing afterwards only gives names with blank values of `{}`. Why?

```
page.Fields.Foo = "asdf";
var test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(page); // shows Foo=asdf in the json

// attach all fields to the page object, casting to an IDictionary to be able to add var names
var props = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
{
    if (key.StartsWith("Fields."))
    {
        var fieldName = key.Substring(key.IndexOf(".") + 1);
        props.Add(fieldName, Request.Form[key]);
    }
}

var test2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(props); // blank values of {}
page.Fields = props as ExpandoObject;

// loses the values for the Fields property
test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(page);
```

**UPDATE** the curse of Nancy strikes, the `Request.Form` values turned out to be dynamic, so I had to `.ToString()` it to make it fit into the expected `IDictionary<string,string>`

Comment: You want  a dynamic, not an ExpandoObject, instead of "var props" use "dynamic props"

Comment: Json.NET can serialize dictionaries - in fact, a Json object is a JavaScript dictionary. Perhaps you should create and serialize a `Dictionaty<string,string>` from your Form.Keys instead of going through an intermediary object

Comment: No, it has to be `var props` not `dynamic props`, because it's casting it to an IDictionary<string,string> not as dynamic.

Comment: You can cast the dynamic to a IDictionary.

Comment: @user3791372 it *shouldn't* be cast to anything. You can't use an ExpandoObject in a dynamic way unless you use the `dynamic` keyword

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Using an expando object as the base is very useful, think about this, you create the dynamic expando, add dynamically unknown properties casting it to a dictionary and then you pass the dynamic to other functions which operate the variable as a true dynamic.

Comment: @Gusman not in this case. Here it's used locally as a dictionary.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You're assuming this is the full code and not an example...

Answer (score 3):

To correctly serialize the data you must declare the variable as dynamic, not as an ExpandoObject, JSON .net uses reflection to retrieve properties, if it's a dynamic it casts it as an ExpandoObject and uses the keys as property names, but if you pass the ExpandoObject directly it tries to retrieve the properties from the ExpandoObject type.

Just change

```
var props = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
```

to

```
var props = new ExpandoObject();
var iProps = props as IDictionary<string, Object>;
```

Use iProps to add the data and pass props to the serialization.

EDIT:

You're storing the value in "Page.Fields", this must be dynamic also.

Comment: Why use an Expando? Just create a Dictionary<> in this case

Comment: Because the question asks about using an ExpandoObject, not about using a dictionary.

Comment: The question shows that Expando is used to pull key/value data from Form.Keys. The Expando is used as a dictionary without any dynamic benefit

Comment: This can be perfectly a reduced example, making assumptions is dangerous.

Comment: still doesn't work when serializing to json as the values are still {}

Comment: @user3791372 It should, are you passing props, yes? not iProps.

Comment: "still doesn't work when serializing to json as the values are still {}" -- @user3791372 giving a compilable example would help.

Comment: Argh! the curse of dynamic strikes. The type of `Request.Form[key]` itself is a dynamic value. A `.ToString()` resolved the issue....

Comment: the existance of `var props` and `iProps` is unneeded, a simple `var props = page.Fields as IDictionary<string, Object>;` will suffice¬

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspect it's a defect and you are not getting anything for `Request.Form.Keys` that's matches `Field.` criteria.

your code works fine for me if I've a `page` class with `dynamic Fields` property